# Error during connection with WebSocket in Python : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, function, websocket

I'm trying to set up a connection via WebSocket for retrieving data from Cryptocurrency market. I'm not new to programming, but I mainly used C++ basic knowledge since now. I learned a bit of Python because it seemed more simple to setup, and went to read WebSocket documentation.

I managed to build up something good, retrieve information from Binance and convert them into variables to manipulate. The problem is that while the program is running, I randomly get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in connection
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 353, in recv
    opcode, data = self.recv_data()
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 376, in recv_data
    opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 416, in recv_data_frame
    self.pong(frame.data)
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 342, in pong
    self.send(payload, ABNF.OPCODE_PONG)
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 282, in send
    return self.send_frame(frame)
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 303, in send_frame
    data = frame.format()
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 238, in format
    mask_key = self.get_mask_key(4)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

It seems to pop up randomly, as I wrote down at which loop it appeared, and it's never the same: sometimes after 30 loops, sometimes after 200 loops.

It seems to me that there could be a "str" variable called as a function, in the library, but I really don't know how to resolve this problem.

The code of the program is the following:

```
import websocket
import json

socket = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/xrpusdt@kline_5m' 

def on_message(message):

 json_message = json.loads(message)
 candle = json_message['k']
 is_closed = candle['x']
 open = candle['o']
 close = candle['c']
 high = candle['h']
 low = candle['l']
 vol = candle['v']
 print("Apertura: ", open)
 print("Chiusura: ", close) 
 print("Massimo: ", high)
 print("Minimo: ", low)
 print("Volume: ",vol)
 print("Candela chiusa: ", is_closed)
 return(open,close,high,low,vol,is_closed)


def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
 print("Connection closed")

ws = websocket.WebSocket(socket)


def connection():
 data = ws.recv()
 o,c,h,l,v,ic = on_message(data)
 #variabili convertite in float
 open_f = float(o)
 close_f = float(c)
 high_f = float(h)
 low_f = float(l)
 v_f = float(v)
 #variazione percentuale
 var_perc = ((close_f/open_f)-1)*100
 print("Variazione: ", var_perc,"%")
 var_perc = ((close_f/open_f)-1)*100*75
 print("Variazione con leva x75: ", var_perc,"%")
 print("\n")
 return(open_f,close_f,high_f,low_f,v_f,var_perc,ic)

a=0

while 'true':

 ws.connect(socket, suppress_origin=True)
 open,close,high,low,volume,var,is_closed = connection()
 ws.close()
 a=a+1
 print(str(a))
```

The variable 'a' is just for counting loops, and I tried to remove that feature, keep having the trouble, so it's not that.

Thanks a lot if anyone would help, and I'm not a professional programmer, so please don't yell at me if the matter was easy to solve, because I really tried to find myself a solution.

Comment: One simple suggestion, could you format your code properly, right now the code provided is not valid Python code, given that Python is sensitive to identation.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't able to use TAB key because of the browser functionality that shift textbox instead of adding space.
I added manually the space, i hope it'd be good. For me is working (i wrote same layout on txt file and when i paste on python shell, it works)

Comment: What library are you using for websocket? I mean, how did you install it? In order to be able to reproduce your error

Comment: I've installed 'websocket' and 'websocket-client' using the shell command 'pip install websocket' and 'pip install websocket-client'